# How to disable radio button in a radio group in quiz application in android

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I have developed an quiz based android application in which I'm loading question and answers from an array everything works fine but only issue I'm facing is after selecting an option for a particular question and submitting it the selected option remains selected for the next question also here I need to clear the checked option. Here is what I have tried

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {

        RadioButton uans = (RadioButton)findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ansText, 5000).show();

        if(ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[flag]))
        {

            correct++;
        }
        else
        {
            wrong++;
        }

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Flag before INCR==> " + flag, 5000).show();

        flag++;


        if(flag < ques.length)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Flag after INCR==> " + flag, 5000).show();
            rg1.setEnabled(false);
            t2.setText(ques[flag]);
            r1.setText(options[flag*4]);
            r2.setText(options[flag*4 + 1]);
            r3.setText(options[flag*4 + 2]);
            r4.setText(options[flag*4 + 3]);
        }
```

Comment: @Zubair Ahmad Khan how to solve this? am I doing wrong anywhere?

Comment: `disable radio button` and `selecting an option` and `remains selected` and `clear the checked option`. Well what is it really?

Comment: Could you post onCreate method as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uans.setChecked(false); - from your code this is getting the checked radio button from the group (rg1).

[Tip](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html): If you need to change the radio button state yourself (such as when loading a saved CheckBoxPreference), use the setChecked(boolean) or toggle() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your `RadioButtons` in a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) then when you move to the next question just clear them all with [clearCheck()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck()) method (`RadioGroup.clearCheck();`)